# get directory from file path c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is the simplest way to get the directory that a file is in? I'm using this to find the working directory.

```
string filename = "C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat"
```

In this example, I should get "C:\MyDirectory".

Comment: Pet hate: is that a narrow STL string? You should be using Unicode strings for all file handling on Windows.

Comment: @Rup: really? Does the encoding matter when looking for `'/'` and `'\'`? As long as you are not interpreting the strings as ASCII/Latin1/whatever wrong assumption

Comment: @sehe No, sure, if the string is UTF-8 then you won't have problems with internationalisation etc. or someone feeding you a file with a Japanese name. But only UTF-8, and there's no point using UTF-8 when everything else uses UTF-16 - probably including wherever you got the string from in the first place.

Comment: @Rup: so know we know that _you prefer_ UTF16. For your info, Windows treats filenames as _opaque_ arrays of UTF-16 characters. Note also that UTF-16 is _still_ a variable-length character encoding; it doesn't actually buy you much over UTF-8. I would have understood if you argued UCS-2 (_fixed-length characters_) for simplicity of implementation, but then again, windows treats it as UCS-16 anyway

Comment: @nidhal: Better use slashes than backslashes: `"C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat"` contains two `\M` as escape characters. Better use `"C:/MyDirectory/MyFile.bat"` or if it has to be`"C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat"`.

Comment: @sehe Well except when it's parsing the filename for path components obviously :-p My point is really 1) don't use a code page that can't represent all characters as you can easily get in trouble 2) input from the UI is passed as UTF-16, names from the filesystem APIs are passed as UTF-16, filenames you read from the registry etc. are passed as UTF-16, and all filesystem APIs accept UTF-16 characters: there's very rarely a good reason to make a round-trip to UTF-8. You're just making trouble for yourself, and if you define your API to accept UTF-8 filenames only you're making trouble for me.

Comment: @Rup: At least with UTF-8 [you can parse it for filename components just fine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Compared_to_other_multi-byte_encodings) (bullets 1 and 4) without interpreting byte sequences (possibly true for UTF-16 as well). Also, for general interest, see ['Should UTF-16 be considered harmful?'](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful)

Comment: why reinvent the wheel, dear colleagues? Use libraries for that that have been tested and written by people who might know what they're doing.

Comment: Rejected attempted edit. Nubok, if you see this, **please do not correct *questions* with edits**, and **please do not delete important information from answers**.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The initialisation is incorrect as you need to escape the backslashes:

```
string filename = "C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat";
```

To extract the directory if present:

```
string directory;
const size_t last_slash_idx = filename.rfind('\\');
if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx)
{
    directory = filename.substr(0, last_slash_idx);
}
```

Comment: it's the answer only for the part, which is 'In this example, I should get...'. For a correct solution, a path handling library or an OS call should be used.

Comment: Fails if the filename (legitimately) uses *forward* slashes. Also fails to get the (absolute) directory if the filename is relative. Also relies on encoding being set correctly. I wouldn't flag this as "correct" when there's Offirmo's (portable) Boost solution.

Answer (score 26):

The quick and dirty:

Note that you **must** also look for `/` because it is allowed alternative path separator on Windows

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string dirnameOf(const std::string& fname)
{
     size_t pos = fname.find_last_of("\\/");
     return (std::string::npos == pos)
         ? ""
         : fname.substr(0, pos);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
     const std::string fname = "C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat";

     std::cout << dirnameOf(fname) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Use the [Boost.filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-decomposition) parent_path() function.

Ex. argument *c:/foo/bar* => *c:/foo*

More examples here : [path decomposition table](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Path-decomposition-table) and tutorial [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html#Using-path-decomposition).

Comment: Not everyone uses boost.

Comment: IIANM, this doesn't work when the path is a filename-only (i.e. you get an empty path).

Answer (score 15):

C++17 provides [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path). It may be available in C++11 in ; link with -lstdc++fs. Note the function does not validate the path exists; use std::filesystem::status to determine type of file (which may be filetype::notfound)

Comment: Great answer IF a person is using c++17.  From what I see, that's where it was finally adopted.

Answer (score 13):

The MFC way;

```
#include <afx.h>

CString GetContainingFolder(CString &file)
{
    CFileFind fileFind;
    fileFind.FindFile(file);
    fileFind.FindNextFile();
    return fileFind.GetRoot();
}
```

or, even simpler

```
CString path(L"C:\\my\\path\\document.txt");
path.Truncate(path.ReverseFind('\\'));
```

Comment: 1st example requires file to be present

Comment: There is not CString.Truncate method https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms908314.aspx

Comment: @OneWorld That's interesting.  Not sure where I found that. How about `CString::Left`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms928948.aspx

Comment: OP didn't ask about MFC, rather specifically c++.

Comment: @CraigB MFC is a library for c++

Answer (score 11):

Since C++17 you can use [std::filesystem::parent_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path):

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string filename = "C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat";
    std::string directory = std::filesystem::path(filename).parent_path().u8string();
    std::cout << directory << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: When working with files name I have found it to be very convenient to use the raw strings syntax mostly because it is less error prone and easier on the eyes. R"(C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat)";

Answer (score 6):

As Question is old but I would like to add an answer so that it will helpful for others.
in Visual c++ you can use CString or char array also

```
CString filename = _T("C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat");  
PathRemoveFileSpec(filename);
```

> **OUTPUT:**
>
> C:\MyDirectory

Include `Shlwapi.h` in your header files.

[MSDN LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748(v=vs.85).aspx) here you can check example.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Check Andrew Kozlov's answer

Comment: Lot's of c++ is on systems that don't have CString.

Comment: This is not the greatest example of the function's usage. It takes a pointer to a mutable char array as input parameter, ATL CStrings just happen to implicitly convert to that, but the function is usable with any C-style string. ``BOOL PathRemoveFileSpec(char* pszPath)``

Answer (score 5):

You can use the _spliltpath function available in stdlib.h header. Please refer to this link for the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273364%28v=VS.60%29.aspx

Comment: Given the lack of a C#-like dirname function, this is absolutely the best method, as it doesn't depend on the format of the path.

Answer (score 5):

A very simple cross-platform solution (as adapted from [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) for `string::find_last_of`):

```
std::string GetDirectory (const std::string& path)
{
    size_t found = path.find_last_of("/\\");
    return(path.substr(0, found));
}
```

This works for both cases where the slashes can be either backward or forward pointing (or mixed), since it merely looks for the last occurrence of either in the string `path`.

However, my personal preference is using the Boost::Filesystem libraries to handle operations like this.  An example:

```
std::string GetDirectory (const std::string& path)
{
    boost::filesystem::path p(path);
    return(p.parent_path().string());
}
```

Although, if getting the directory path from a string is the only functionality you need, then Boost might be a bit overkill (especially since Boost::Filesystem is one of the few Boost libraries that aren't header-only).  However, AFIK, Boost::Filesystem had been approved to be included into the TR2 standard, but might not be fully available until the C++14 or C++17 standard (likely the latter, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27820633)), so depending on your compiler (and when you're reading this), you may not even need to compile these separately anymore since they might be included with your system already.  For example, Visual Studio 2012 can already use some of the TR2 filesystem components (according to [this post](http://cpprocks.com/introduction-to-tr2-filesystem-library-in-vs2012/)), though I haven't tried it since I'm still using Visual Studio 2010...

Answer (score 1):

This is proper winapi solution:

```
CString csFolder = _T("c:\temp\file.ext");
PathRemoveFileSpec(csFolder.GetBuffer(0));
csFolder.ReleaseBuffer(-1);
```

Comment: "This function is deprecated. We recommend the use of the PathCchRemoveFileSpec function in its place." Otherwise this **is** the proper answer, so a +1 from me

Comment: OP didn't mention winapi.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Qt, you can also do it like this:

```
std::string getDirectory(const std::string & file_path)
{
   return QFileInfo(QString(file_path)).absolutePath().toStdString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way of Beetle)

```
#include<tchar.h>

int GetDir(TCHAR *fullPath, TCHAR *dir) {
    const int buffSize = 1024;

    TCHAR buff[buffSize] = {0};
    int buffCounter = 0;
    int dirSymbolCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < _tcslen(fullPath); i++) {
        if (fullPath[i] != L'\\') {
            if (buffCounter < buffSize) buff[buffCounter++] = fullPath[i];
            else return -1;
        } else {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < buffCounter; i2++) {
                dir[dirSymbolCounter++] = buff[i2];
                buff[i2] = 0;
            }

            dir[dirSymbolCounter++] = fullPath[i];
            buffCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    return dirSymbolCounter;
}
```

Using :

```
TCHAR *path = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
TCHAR  dir[1024] = {0};

GetDir(path, dir);
wprintf(L"%s\n%s\n", path, dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply search the last "\" and then cut the string:

```
string filePath = "C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat" 
size_t slash = filePath.find_last_of("\");
string dirPath = (slash != std::string::npos) ? filePath.substr(0, slash) : filePath;
```

make sure in Linux to search "/" instead of "\":

`size_t slash = filePath.find_last_of("/");`