# c++ how to remove filename from path string

Tags: c++, string, filesystems

I have

```
const char *pathname = "..\somepath\somemorepath\somefile.ext";
```

how to transform that into

```
"..\somepath\somemorepath"
```

?

Comment: Boost has a nice `filesystem::path` class...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) member function of `std::string`

```
string s1("../somepath/somemorepath/somefile.ext");
string s2("..\\somepath\\somemorepath\\somefile.ext");
cout << s1.substr(0, s1.find_last_of("\\/")) << endl;
cout << s2.substr(0, s2.find_last_of("\\/")) << endl;
```

This solution works with both forward and back slashes.

Comment: It works assuming the user never puts whichever slash is legal into his filenames

Comment: Did not work for me, but this did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518743/get-directory-from-file-path-c

Answer (score 10):

On Windows use [`_splitpath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx) and on Linux use [`dirname()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname)

Answer (score 7):

On Windows 8, use [`PathCchRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707092(v=vs.85).aspx) which can be found in `Pathcch.h`

[`PathCchRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707092(v=vs.85).aspx) will remove the last element in a path, so if you pass it a directory path, the last folder will be stripped.
If you would like to avoid this, and you are unsure if a file path is a directory, use [`PathIsDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773621(v=vs.85).aspx)

[`PathCchRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707092(v=vs.85).aspx) does not behave as expected on paths containing forwards slashes.

Answer (score 3):

use `strrchr()` to find the last backslash and strip the string.

```
char *pos = strrchr(pathname, '\\');
if (pos != NULL) {
   *pos = '\0'; //this will put the null terminator here. you can also copy to another string if you want
}
```

Comment: What if it's a forward slash (`/`) instead?

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have access to c++17 it should be something like this:

```
std::filesystem::path fullpath(path_string);
fullpath.remove_filename();
cout << fullpath.string();
```

If you don't have c++17, but have access to boost, you can do the same thing with boost::filesystem::path.

Using one of these libraries has the advantage of being compatible with multiple operating systems.

Comment: This is the best answer, since it is OS agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

PathRemoveFileSpec(...) you dont need windows 8 for this.
you will need to include Shlwapi.h and Shlwapi.lib
but they are winapi so you dont need any special SDK