# Get Directory name from a LPTSTR in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Using

```
LPTSTR  strDLLPath1 = new TCHAR[_MAX_PATH];
::GetModuleFileName((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, strDLLPath1, _MAX_PATH);
```

I get path to my DLL which it correctly prints.

```
D:\Test\work\EasyDLL\Debug\EasyDLL.dll
```

Now I just need the `"D:\Test\work\EasyDLL\Debug\"`.

Given my experience using VC++ can you guide me in best way to do that - any string replace, conversion etc.

Comment: See the [`_splitpath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function, or the [Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) [`path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) class.

Comment: Or _splitpath_s, as _splitpath is deprecated...

Comment: Example using `std::string` member functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518743/get-directory-from-file-path-c/8518793#8518793

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [shell patch handling functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and more precisely at [PathRemoveFileSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748%28v=vs.85%29.asp), which does exactly what you want.

You will need to link with shlwapi.lib.

Comment: that really solved my problem as of now. any issues seen as of now in terms of compatibility across windows platforms by any one?