# What is the status of C++ TR2 Filesystem library?

Tags: c++, std

What is the status of C++ TR2 Filesystem library as of last Bristol meeting? Will it be part of C++1Y (C++14?) or is it suspended or are there any known recent comments as of the last three meetings?

Comment: According to http://isocpp.org/std/status, new major libraries will be separate documents, not part of the language standard; so it will be released separately to C++14. It certainly doesn't appear in the latest draft (http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has [recently been unanimously approved by the ISO committee](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/256220) but did not make it in time for C++14. Though all the TSs (filesytem, library fundamentals, networking, etc.) are expected to be independently available ahead of C++17, I believe the intention is that if they are ready in time, they will be rolled into C++17, as happened with TR1 and C++11.

Comment: The link is broken.