# How to check if a path refers to a volume in Windows with C++17's filesystem?

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems, c++17

I'm working with C++17 on Windows. As far as I can see, `std::filesystem` doesn't have an `is_root()` function or something similar that tells me if a path refers directly to C: or D: or any other volumen. Am I missing something?

Currently I'm doing this:

```
if (path.parent_path() == path)
{
    //
}
```

It looks like it's working, but I don't know if this misses any edge cases. Is there a better way?

### EDIT:

I want to check if the entirety of the path is *just* the volume name (maybe followed by an optional slash or backslash).

So, if there was a function like this, I'd like it to behave as follows:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
is_root(fs::path{ "C:" }); // true
is_root(fs::path{ "D:\\"}); // true
is_root(fs::path{ "C:/users" }) // false
is_root(fs::current_path()) // usually false, unless the executable was started directly in C: or D: or any other drive
```

Comment: Are you asking if a path has a volume name in it, or if the entirety of the path is *just* a volume name?

Comment: @NicolBolas the entirety of the path shall be *just* that volumen name. I will clarify that in my question. Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518743/get-directory-from-file-path-c) answer the question? Obviously use find instead of rfind.

Comment: @Cortex not really. I want to know if my path **is** the volume (the root of it), not if it contains a volume.

Comment: Yes but if the filepath does not contain // then it is the volume yes?

Comment: I don't have a windows installation right here, but wouldn't it be better to use [std::filesystem::path::root_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/root_path) on `path` and then check if they are equal?

Comment: @t.niese I was thinking about that, too. But I'm not sure, hence I asked this question

Comment: @Cortex the function/algorithm I'm looking for shall return `true` on `fs::path{"C:"}` as well as on `fs::path{"C:/"}` as well as on `fs::path{"C:\\"}`

Comment: @sebrockm: That's a bit more complicated than what you seemed to ask for in your question. Those latter two paths also have a root directory in them; they don't just specify the volume. You really should put that in the question.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks, I thought that with or without (back)slash this either way refers to the root of a drive. Added that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check to see if it `has_root_name()`; without one, it obviously doesn't specify a volume.

The hard part is to figure out if it *only* has a root-name. That's complicated because you also want to ignore the root-directory of the path if it specifies one.

The iterator range is a good, performance-friendly solution here. If it has a root-name, then `begin()` points to that root-name. So if you increment it, it points to the next component in the path.

If the path has both a root-name and a root-directory, then the component after the root-name is the root-directory. So if you increment past *that*, the iterator either is pointing to an additional component or it has reached the `end` of the range. And if it's at the `end`, then there's nothing left and you know that the path is "just a volume".

The code would look like this:

```
bool is_volume(const fs::path &p)
{
  if(!p.has_root_name()) return false;

  auto it = p.begin();
  ++it; //Skip the root-name

  if(p.has_root_directory())
    ++it; //Skip the root-directory.

  if(it == p.end())
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: I was not aware that the slash behind the root name matters. I always thought it was optional. Then I need to clarify if for my task if I really need to cover "C:" as well. Either way, this looks good. I will test it.

Comment: @sebrockm: The path "c:" specifies the volume "c:". The path "c:\" specifies the *root directory* of the volume "c:". Each volume has its own current directory; the path "c:name" specifies the "name" file/directory in the current directory of the "c:" volume. By contrast, "c:\name" specifies the "name" file/directory in the root directory of the "c:" volume.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Note that drive "X:" is implemented as a link in the object namespace. The link usually targets a volume device, but it may target an arbitrary path on a local or remote device (e.g. a subst or mapped drive). So not all root paths on a DOS drive, e.g. "X:\", are actually volume mountpoints.

Comment: Also, a volume device has other usable names, such as "\\?\BootPartition" or "\\?\Volume{GUID}", set via `DefineDosDeviceW`. So some paths without a drive-letter name are actually volume mountpoint paths, e.g. "\\?\BootPartition\".

Comment: Also, a filesystem directory may be a junction to a local device path. If it targets a filesystem directory, then it's a mountpoint, and if it's the root path of a reserved "\\?\Volume{GUID}" name, then it's a volume mountpoint. Thus "C:\Mount\BackupDrive" may also be a volume mountpoint path.